QGIS atlas with defined layers fitted to each map
I am creating an atlas where I want two specific layers to be fitted in every map. The distance between layers vary so map scale needs to be different in each map. Right now I can move the atlas coverage layer point to the left or right side of the map, depending on the attribute.
xMin: if([myAttributeCondition], xmin(@atlas_geometry) - 100, NULL)
xMax: if([myAttributeCondition], xmax(@atlas_geometry) + 100, NULL)
This works fine.
Problem is that I want another map layer to be shown in every map on the opposite side of atlas geometry point. So if the point is on left side of the map, another layer should be on the right side and vice versa.

What's the type of layers  ? point ?
What's version of qgis are you using ?
Can you provide example pictures of you actual results and the results needed ?
It help to understand your problematic.

You can get the bounding box of both corresponding features and then use the method you already tried to fit the extent of the map.
Generate an Atlas with layer_a (change for your own layer name) as the coverage layer, then enter this expression for the X min of the Map item.
x_min(
    bounds(
        collect_geometries(
            geometry(@atlas_feature),
            overlay_nearest(
                layer:='layer_b',          -- change for your own layer name
                expression:=@geometry, 
                limit:=1
            )[0]
        )
    )
) - 100

Repeat for Y min, X max, Y max ensuring to change - for + for the maxes.
The map scale will automatically update to accommodate the features from both layers.

Note: overlay_nearest() was used to find the corresponding feature in this example, but this can easily be switched out for a matching attribute such as a name or code.
